# Looping dynamic objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am currently developing a system where I have 2 dropdown list which is the model and destination. However, the destination is a dynamic dropdown list and is dependent on the model that is chosen by the user and will only be added on button click. On button click, the dynamic dropdown list, textbox and label should display one at a time depending on the chosen destination.

My problem is I've messed up my for loop because it displays all the dropdown list's values on every button click without considering the chosen dropdown list value. Please help me. I've been debugging this for a week and I'm still learning javascript/jQuery.

Here is my progress so far:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("addbtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    createOptionList();
  });
};

function createOptionList() {

  var destination = document.getElementById("destination");
  var letter = document.getElementById('model').value;
  if (letter != "select") {
    var array = [`${letter}.1`, `${letter}.2`, `${letter}.3`, `${letter}.4`];
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
    destination.appendChild(selectList);

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

      var option = document.createElement("option");
      var des = document.getElementById("destination");
      var br = document.createElement("br");

      option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
      option.text = array[i];
      selectList.appendChild(option);
      destination.appendChild(br);
    }
    dynamicObjects();
  }
}

function dynamicObjects() {

  var cri = document.getElementById("criteria").value
  var criteria = document.getElementById("criteria");
  var qty = document.getElementById("qty");
  var cell = document.getElementById("cell");
  var option = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
  var blank = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement("span");
    var textbox = document.createElement("input");
    var textbox1 = document.createElement("input");
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    blank = option[i].innerText;

    if (blank == "Model-A.1") {
      wrapper.className = blank;
      textbox.className = blank;
      wrapper.innerText = "Good/n";
      criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
      criteria.appendChild(br);
      qty.appendChild(textbox)
      qty.appendChild(br)
      cell.appendChild(textbox1)
      cell.appendChild(br)

    } else if (blank == "Model-A.2") {
      wrapper.className = blank;
      textbox.className = blank;
      wrapper.innerText = "Fine/n";
      criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
      criteria.appendChild(br);
      qty.appendChild(textbox)
      qty.appendChild(br)
      cell.appendChild(textbox1)
      cell.appendChild(br)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
th, td {
 padding:15px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <table class = "table">
  <tr>
    <td> MODEL: </td>
    <td>
      <select id="model" name="model" onchange="populate(this.id, 
  'destination')">
        <option value="select">--Select Model--</option>
        <option value="Model-A">Model-A</option>
        <option value = "Model-B"> Model-B </option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="addbtn" value="Add Destination"/>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
      <th><center> DESTINATION: </th></center>
      <th><center> CRITERIA: </th></center>
      <th><center> QTY: </th></center>
      <th><center> CELL: </th></center>
  </tr>   
<tr>
    <td width = "140">
      <center>
        <div id="destination" style = "width:230px; 
word-wrap: break-word">
      </center>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width = "140">
      <center>
        <div id="criteria" style = "width:350px; 
word-wrap: break-word">
      </center>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td width = "140">
      <center>
        <div id = "qty" required>
        </td>
      </center>
    <td width = "140">
      <center>
        <div id = "cell" required>
        </td>
      </center>
</tr>
```

Comment: Before anything, please, consider using some tool to validate your HTML, because it have a lot of invalid syntax and wrong closed tags, also `<center>` is not used anymore because it is deprecated.

Comment: Noted @CalvinNunes. As I've stated, I'm still learning but still, thanks for that :)

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: I'd also make sure to fix your code indentation before posting the question. It's kind of difficult to parse the structure of things otherwise.

Comment: I'll work on that. Thanks @Jacob

Comment: I know the problem is on the loop. How can I display it one by one in accordance to the chosen destination value

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what the code is supposed to do. I get an error when trying to run it: `populate is not defined`. Are you missing some code?

Comment: Choose a model and (ignore the error) click the button add destination @Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't need a loop at all in your `dynamicObjects`. Loops are for doing a thing 0 to many times. You only want to do one thing. If your concern is how to get the selected option, use the `value` property of your `model` dropdown:

```
function dynamicObjects() {

  var cri = document.getElementById("criteria").value
  var criteria = document.getElementById("criteria");
  var qty = document.getElementById("qty");
  var cell = document.getElementById("cell");
  var blank = "";

  var wrapper = document.createElement("span");
  var textbox = document.createElement("input");
  var textbox1 = document.createElement("input");
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  blank = document.getElementById('model').value;

  if (blank == "Model-A.1") {
    wrapper.className = blank;
    textbox.className = blank;
    wrapper.innerText = "Good/n";
    criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
    criteria.appendChild(br);         
    qty.appendChild(textbox)
    qty.appendChild(br)
    cell.appendChild(textbox1)
    cell.appendChild(br)    
  } else if (blank == "Model-A.2") {
    wrapper.className = blank;
    textbox.className = blank;
    wrapper.innerText = "Fine/n";
    criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
    criteria.appendChild(br);
    qty.appendChild(textbox)
    qty.appendChild(br)
    cell.appendChild(textbox1)         
    cell.appendChild(br)
  }
}
```

You should also do a favor and follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. Look at what's common for those two cases, convert those to parameters, and extract a function. You could also consider using an object to declaratively set up a model representing how you build your destinations. In this case, the only thing different between the two models is your criteria, so you can do something like this to de-duplicate the code:

```
const models = {
  'Model-A.1': {
    criteria: 'Good'
  },
  'Model-A.2': {
    criteria: 'Fine'
  }
};

function dynamicObjects() {
  var cri = document.getElementById("criteria").value
  var criteria = document.getElementById("criteria");
  var qty = document.getElementById("qty");
  var cell = document.getElementById("cell");
  var blank = "";

  var wrapper = document.createElement("span");
  var textbox = document.createElement("input");
  var textbox1 = document.createElement("input");
  var br = document.createElement("br");
  model = models[document.getElementById('model').value];

  // TODO: handle the case where nothing is selected
  if (!model) {
    return;
  }

  wrapper.className = blank;
  textbox.className = blank;
  wrapper.innerText = model.criteria;
  criteria.appendChild(wrapper);
  criteria.appendChild(br);         
  qty.appendChild(textbox)
  qty.appendChild(br)
  cell.appendChild(textbox1)
  cell.appendChild(br)    
}
```

Comment: It's not displaying the criteria's label and cell and qty's textbox though @Jacob

Comment: I think you really need to clarify what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: On button click, it should display the destination (according to the model), the criteria according to the chosen destination and a texbox for the cell and qty @Jacob

Comment: And btw, thanks for that information @Jacob. I will always take note of that

Comment: You'll need a separate event handler for when you select a destination if you want things to change when selecting it.

Comment: That is what dynamicObjects supposed to be that's why there is a conditional statement in it @Jacob

Comment: I wonder if may you have a misconception about loops versus events. When you're looping over the options, you aren't defining the code that will run for each item in the list, but rather you're just running the code for each of the items right away. If you need something to happen in response to a dropdown selection, add a `change` event with `addEventListener` like you did for the click event of the button.

Comment: Okay Im so sorry @Jacob I'm so lost lol so in my dynamic dropdown list which is the destination I will add addEventListener such as document.getElementById("destination").addEventListener("change"), function(){}?